# Paypal Adaptive Payment 540031 Error

Tags: php, paypal

I am using the Mobile SDK to integrate paypal payments into my iOS app.  I'm trying to verify an adaptive payment but keep getting

540031 Error : You do not have permission to get these payment details

whenever I try to use https://svcs.sandbox.paypal.com/AdaptivePayments/PaymentDetails.
I am using my sandbox business credentials.  What do I have to do to get permission?

Comment: This might be a better fit in the PayPal Dev Forums, they have a FAQ on this.

Answer (score 1):

Don't forget to replace

```
window.plugins.PayPalMobile.setEnvironment("PayPalEnvironmentNoNetwork");
```

by

```
window.plugins.PayPalMobile.setEnvironment("PayPalEnvironmentSandbox");
```

for Sandbox or

```
window.plugins.PayPalMobile.setEnvironment("PayPalEnvironmentProduction");
```

for Live

in your Javascript code, the one that you modified from the sample [here](https://github.com/paypal/PayPal-iOS-SDK-PhoneGap)

;) enjoy your tests